# Spring Boot REST API disable Form Login redirect

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to figure out something that I would expect to work out of the box these days.

I am building an API with Spring Boot backend and I will create a react front end.

I only have one server so I dont need to use tokens. I want the same normal server side sessions and cookies.

I managed to get the Authentication to work but for some reason it keeps redirecting after success to the default / endpoint.

I really do not want this to happen and can't figure out why this is the case. I also can't find any decent resources on the internet of people that have encountered this issue.

I have seen a few videos where I have seen people handling the login in a Rest Controller end point rather than using filters. I assume this could work but then how would I implement session management?

Here is the code so far:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthUserService authUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(authUserService);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("AUTH_USER")
                .mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        http.cors();

        http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfHandlerFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        http.addFilterAt(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Authentication Filter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthenticationFilter(){
        super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("Custom Authentication Filter fired!");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Login login = new Login();
        try {
            login = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), Login.class);
        } catch (StreamReadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DatabindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            login.getUsername(),
            login.getPassword()
        );

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);

    }


}
```

Login Model class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Login {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

I want a normal server side session. I am not using JWT just because it is a JavaScript client. But all I want is for it to not redirect. Is this possible?
Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, @theMyth. Any reason you aren't using HTTP Basic? You can use a JSESSIONID with it so that you are only providing the credentials once. Also it's nice b/c HTTP Basic doesn't redirect by default.

Comment: I could try this. For now, I had to remove the filter and create a Rest Controller and point to process the authentication there

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to approach this, depending on your preference.

Certainly, you can stand up your own Spring MVC endpoint and set the `SecurityContext` yourself. Spring Security's `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will store the `SecurityContext` in an `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` by default, which induces the container to write a `JSESSIONID` session cookie that can be used on subsequent requests.

The main reason to go this route is if you want to have access to the MVC feature set when writing this endpoint.

One downside of this route is that Spring Security 6 will [no longer save the security context](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10949) for you when it comes to custom MVC endpoints, so you would need to be aware of that when upgrading.

#### HTTP Basic

That said, it doesn't seem like your requirements are so sophisticated that you can't use Spring Security's OOTB behavior.

One way to do this is with [HTTP Basic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.1/servlet/authentication/passwords/basic.html). Note that for simplicity, I'll publish the `SecurityFilterChain` as a `@Bean` instead of using the now-deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .mvcMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("AUTH_USER")
            .mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        )
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .cors(Customizer.witHDefaults())
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHandlerFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

This will allow you to send the username/password using the `Authorization: Basic` header. There's no need in this case for you to stand up anything custom. The filter chain will store the security
context in the session, and your Javascript can call endpoints using the `JSESSIONID` or by resending the username/password creds.

#### AuthenticationSuccessHandler

If for some reason you want to use [form login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.1/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html) (what your sample is customizing right now), instead of creating a custom filter, you can configure the existing form login filter with an [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-abstractprocessingfilter) that does not redirect:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .mvcMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("AUTH_USER")
            .mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        )
        .formLogin((form) -> form
            .successHandler((request, response, authentication) ->    
                response.setStatusCode(200)
            )
        )
        .cors(Customizer.witHDefaults())
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHandlerFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

Once again, the filter chain will save the subsequent `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to the session and issue a `JSESSIONID` for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this first thing tomorrow. So can this work with a form sent in JSON format with HttpBasic? Im sorry this might be a lame question, I think I finally figured the difference between http basic & form login. I want to be able to send a post request to the server with username and password.

Comment: Why does it need to be via JSON? I think most frameworks have support for the HTTP Basic header as it's a common standard. Generally speaking, it's best to use a common security standard when possible.

Comment: If you do need JSON, then Spring MVC is the easiest way since it's provided OOTB.

Comment: Thanks, Im still not very experienced, so please forgive me for asking lame things. I think maybe I was mislead into thinking that HttpBasic is not secure, I will try this tomorrow. This is a project which is like a playground for me, I want to get a deeper understanding about how things work. So I wanted to know how to be able to do a form login. I have finally managed to get it to work, but I had to eliminate the filter and use a Rest Endpoint. I guess when its from the same server, a redirect isn't all that bad

Comment: Just to confirm one thing, so if I had to use a Post login form, then you suggest authenticating in a REST endpoint? & setting the security context there instead of a filter?

Comment: This is one question that suggests there are a few security issues with HttpBasic?: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https

Comment: It's better if you can use the Spring Security filters since those are vetted by the community and are very stable. Even with login, it can be challenging to get security right. For that reason, if you must do form login, I'd recommend that you use Spring Security's defaults (which means not using JSON for that one request).

Comment: As for HTTP Basic, there are no more security issues with it than with form login, so long as you make the call yourself and are using sessions, as you already indicated. In this way, HTTP Basic is simply a standard way to hand the credentials to the backend.